# Error in a content query web part 2007

Tags: content-query-web-part, xslt, item-styles

any one can know what the error in the following code :
when I remove the variable `LinkTarget1` it will run

```
<xsl:template name="INeedTo" match="*" mode="itemstyle">
<xsl:variable name="LinkTarget1">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@URL,',')"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="header">
   <![CDATA[<select class="md-ineedto-slct">]]>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="footer">
    <![CDATA[</select>]]>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=0">
    <xsl:value-of select="$header" disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:if> 

<option value='<xsl:value-of select="$LinkTarget1"/>'>
      <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>  
</option>

<xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*)=0">
    <xsl:value-of select="$footer" disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<option value='{$LinkTarget1}'>
      <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>  
</option>
```

Comment: thanks,but when i used the `{}` the value will be empty

Comment: @Ahmad, Maybe because `substring-before(@URL,',')` returns empty string? Check it. Also, simply use `<xsl:variable name="LinkTarget1" select="substring-before(@URL,',')"/>`